# Bootstrap 4 modal is not displaying

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I have a simple design with an image inside a centered div.  Over the image is a semi-opaque textbox with an h1 element.  I want a bootstrap 4 modal component to pop-up after the h1 is clicked.  I have followed various tutorials for building the modal, but I can't seem to get it working.  I'm not sure what the issue could be.

If someone could take a look and give me some guidance, it would be greatly appreciated.

The CodePen: https://codepen.io/dayna-j/pen/RMZdej?editors=0010

The HTML:

```
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fredericka+the+Great" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

  <div class='img-div'>
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/eZcdEn/nature_3084841_1920.jpg" alt='close up of grass'/>
    <div class='textBox-div'>      
      <h1 class = no-select data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal">Click Me</h1>
    </div>


      <!-- Modal (inside img-div) -->
    <div id="Modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
         </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
.no-select {
user-select: none;
}

html {


 box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  // overflow:hidden;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

* { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}

body{
  background: #232526;
  // background: papayawhip;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  // border: 5px solid green;
  // border-radius: 1000px;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container-fluid {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.img-div {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  // position: relative;
  max-height: 500px;
  max-width: 850px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  // border-radius: 1000px; 
}

.textBox-div { 
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background: whitesmoke;
  opacity: .5;
}

.textBox-div h1 {
  font-family: 'Fredericka the Great', cursive;
  margin: auto 0;
  font-weight: 900;
}

@media screen and (max-width:400px)
{
  h1 {font-size: 1.5em;}
}

@media screen and (max-width:200px)
{
  h1 {font-size: 1em;}
}
```

The JavaScript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('#Modal').modal('hide');


  $('h1').on('click', function(){
    $('#Modal').modal('show');
  });

});
```

Comment: If you open the browser console, you'll see a few errors - specifically, that Bootstrap requires popper.js. It's extremely unlikely that your JS will work as expected so long as you still have errors in the console, so if you can address these it will be clearer if/where the problem lies.

Comment: The problem isn't popper the beta version of Bootstrap doesn't seem to have a `.modal` function. You can use https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js which is stable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with the code...

- You need `popper.js` which is not included on Codepen.
- Having both `data-toggle="modal"` and the JS code to `$('#Modal').modal('show')` are counteracting each other which is **preventing the modal display**.
- The use of `//` in the CSS (html{}) is not a proper comment.

Use `data-toggle="modal"` *or* `$('#Modal').modal('show')`, but not both.

https://www.codeply.com/go/zcHpRWcMA5

---

An **alternate** to linking to `popper.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.css` is to use `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` which combines both..

CDN: `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js`

Answer (score 1):

Link [popper.js](https://popper.js.org/) in your `head`.

Via CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

(From [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/))

Also remove your JS script to show and hide the modal. You don't need it since bootstrap already does it for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('Your model id'))
myModal.show();
```

just this code.

Comment: [Code-only answers are strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69661316/edit) to explain how/why the code solves the problem. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30149728)

Comment: Please provide more details about your code. Thanks